# How to Make Reusable Functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to programming, and to Python. I have written a simple random quote generator which loads various categories of quotes as lists into a dictionary. It then randomly chooses a list and then a specific quote from the list and outputs it to the screen. It is mostly complete but I am looking for ways to clean up the code to make it more efficient. Right now I have a set of 14 different categories that the user can select from to populate the dictionary. Each one of those category selections calls a function to update the dictionary and the config.ini file to save the user preferences. That results in hundreds of lines of near-identical code, where the only differences are the specific category and files in use. I am looking for a way to rewrite it so that the same function can be reused each time and simply pass in the correct information to make it work. I have posted snippets of the relevant code below. I am using Python 3.6 and TKinter. Thank you for any help you can provide.

## Adversity check button to call update_adversity function and add/remove adversity category quotes to/from the dictionary

```
    self.adversity = BooleanVar()
    self.adv = Checkbutton(self, text = 'Adversity/Hardship', variable = self.adversity, command = self.update_adversity)
    self.adv.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = 'W', padx = 0, pady = 0)
    if 'adversity' in quotes:
        self.adversity.set(1)
    elif 'adversity' not in quotes:
        self.adversity.set(0)
```

## add/remove adversity list in dictionary based on checkbutton value

```
def update_adversity(self):
    if self.adversity.get() == True:
        config.set('categories', 'adversity', 'True') # updates config file
        with open('adversity.py', 'r', encoding = 'UTF8') as f:
            new_quotes_added = f.readlines()
            quotes['adversity'] = new_quotes_added
            try:
                del quotes['default']
                config.set('categories', 'default', 'False') # updates config file
                return quotes
            except:
                return quotes
    elif self.adversity.get() == False:
        config.set('categories', 'adversity', 'False') # updates config file
        try:
            del quotes['adversity']
            if quotes == {}:
                with open('default.py', 'r', encoding = 'UTF8') as f:
                    quotes['default'] = f.readlines()
                    config.set('categories', 'default', 'True') # updates config file
                return quotes
            else:
                return quotes
        except:
            return quotes
```

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it, which is generally not appropriate for this site, but you might find better luck at [codereview.se]. Remember to read [their requirements](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: My apologies. I didn't see anything that said this site was only for non-working code. I will try that site. Thank you.